# Where did Star Lord get his boot engines from and how do they work?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

It seems, that Star Lord from the *Guardians of the Galaxy* just couldn't use simple engines, because he has no space for a lot of fuel. One thing left is a nuclear reactor. Did he steal them from Stark, or did he invent it on his own like Stark did?

[image]

Comment: I rephrased the question in your title since the mere fact that there's no room for fuel is absolutely no reason to automatically assume they're nuclear powered. In general, please try to avoid jumping to conclusions and then asking for the truth of those conclusions rather than just asking what you *actually* want to know.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Guardians of the Galaxy tag should be added too.

Comment: As to the tagging. There's no need  for the question to bear tags for every single film Star Lord appears in, when there already is a tag for the MCU in general, no matter if the specific screenshot you used is from *Infinity War*.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Well, can you tell me about one more engine that can be used? There's nothing left, but nuclear reactors. I think that Quill used them.

Comment: In a universe where about *everything magically works*? No, *I* can't tell you another kind of engine, but I'm sure the guy who hides an entire Iron Man suit in a box the size of a coin maybe could. I mean, you've seen the most ridiculous of technology in those films and you're approaching something as banal as a boot rocket with science from the 20th century? To what end?

Comment: You're asking why he has rocket boots, but not how his mask works, or how he has a space ship, or how there's gravity on his spaceship, or how all different races are all speaking English? Additionally, your assertion that he must've used Stark technology is quite needlessly farfetched given that Star Lord already operates in a spacefaring civilization.

Comment: Rocket Boots??? Star Lord is Buddy Pine: confirmed!

Comment: FYI even nuclear powered rockets need reaction mass to actually turn the heat generated in the reactor into a rocket engine.  NERVA engines for example use hydrogen as a reaction mass, that needs to be stored in tanks.  So your observation that "no space left for a lot of fuel" can't be used to as the basis for an assertion that it must be a nuclear reactor.  This is fictional supertech from a spacefaring civilization ... not 20/21st century tech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't jump to conclusions which are made up on assumed/opinion based stuff, like you **think** the shoes have a mini reactor and concluded that Stark is bound to be related somehow, please hold your horses.

Coming to your question,
Notice how Quill's quad-blasters, mask or translator did not surprise you which are a marvel themselves and whose features will surprise you.

In MCU, Quill is the son of Ego, a celestial and brought up by ravagers, notice that the Ravagers know this and try never to harm him or let him be harmed in anyway as they know what a celestial can do if he's angry.

Well, Ravagers are thieves, pirates and whatnot, they travel all around the galaxies and their loots often include fancy tech items apart from units (money).

w.r.t MCU, there is no backstory for how Quill got his boots (or anything) but I'd say Ravagers looted a lot of stuff over time and Yondu gave his best to Starlord, the son of a celestial.
Also, there is a possibility that Ego gave some items for Quill so that his son remains safe. (To Yondu while Quill was young).

Regarding technology, you never know which planet has what technology until shown in movies,we fans can't predict what tech can be seen in future, we enjoy the tech without going into much logic!